# Suitable adjective for implying romantic connections?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective which I could use for example in the following situation:

> "Don't try to understand the joke Joanne said to George; it's a
>   in-joke between romantic partners."

becomes:

> "Don't try to understand the joke Joanne said to George; it's a [X
>   adjective] in-joke."

Does this "X adjective" exist? Is it defined in a thesaurus?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your format is fine. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"lovers' in-joke" is probably simple enough

Comment: Consider that "lovers" can imply a sexual relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure that's any issue. It is specified as romantic in the original post.

Comment: Sure. Just noting.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using **"lovers'"**.  It has some precedent as a non-arbitrary adjective in this context as in, eg., "lovers' quarrel".

> ... it's a lovers' in-joke.

Answer (score 2):

It might be considered a form of **[pillow talk](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/pillow%20talk)**

> Intimate conversation between lovers, typically taking place in bed.

While inside jokes may take place anywhere, the type you describe come from shared, intimate experiences.

While *pillow talk* is a noun phrase, it could be used adjectivally, as in

> Don't try to understand what Joanne said to George, it's a *pillow talk* joke.

Answer (score 1):

I would just say that it's a "relationship in-joke" or a "marriage in-joke", depending on their marital status. Or I would just say, "It's an in-joke between them".